# Show element next to table row on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to implement is when someone hovers over a table row, I want to show up-and-down arrows on the left side of the table (outside of the table). What is the best way to implement this using html/css or jquery?

Comment: Put the arrows inside the `table`, in a cell with hidden borders/content, and show that cell/content on hover of the row.

Comment: What's the purpose of these arrows?  Do they perform some action?  What have you tried?

Comment: Some HTML or a jsfiddle to see what structure you have would be good.

Comment: the arrows are meant to animate the row up or down. I haven't tried much yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it without any JavaScript - with just plain HTML like this:

#### CSS

```css
table {
    margin:     100px;
}

td {
    position:   relative;
}

span.arrow {
    display:    none;
    width:      20px;
    height:     20px;
    position:   absolute;
    left:       -20px;
    border:     1px solid red;
}

tr:hover span.arrow {
    display:    block;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
            Some content
        </td>
        <td>Some content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is just the basic idea. Keep in mind, that the arrow must have a "connection" with the table row, otherwise they will hide again, when you move towards them (because than you would leave the `:hover` of the `<tr>` - that's why the `width` and the amount of `left` are the same in the example).

#### DEMO

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txeEm/)

#### NOTE

I only tested this in Safari. For all other browsers simply move `position: relative;` from `<tr>` to `<table>`:

```
table {
    margin:100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks off in Firefox.

Comment: I had a similar solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tbJ43/ Don't realy agree with the remark though. You could have a visual gap as you can see. The arrows do in fact touch the table, but they are partial transparent.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't test in Firefox. Moving `position: relative;` from `td` to ´table` fixes it.

Comment: @PeterVR your arrows do have a padding and with that it still "touches" the row. Of course, this can be transparent (in my example the whole container is transparent), but there must be no "free space" in-between as this will stop `:hover`.

Comment: that is exactly what i meant, perhaps i explained it bad (not to good with english at this late hour) And don't worry, you already had my vote...

Comment: @PeterVR Thanks. :) And yeah, you're right. Maybe I also tried to hard to explain what could have been told in simpler words. :) So digging' deeper is always good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggleClass` (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with jquery

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td class="arrows">
            <div class="hide">up down</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('.arrows').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('div').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

hide class could simply be display:none;.  You could also use absolute positioning to move them outside the table if you want.